# Can anyone please explain the following dissasembly codes?

Tags: disassembly, assembly, x86, shellcode

Disassembly:

```
0:  31 c9                    xor    ecx,ecx
2:  f7 e1                    mul    ecx
4:  51                       push   ecx
5:  68 2f 2f 73 68           push   0x68732f2f
a:  68 2f 62 69 6e           push   0x6e69622f
f:  89 e3                    mov    ebx,esp
11: b0 0b                    mov    al,0xb
13: cd 80                   int    0x80
15: 51                      push   ecx
16: b0 01                   mov    al,0x1
18: cd 80                   int    0x80
```

Comment: will you please comment what you have tried and where you are struck at a minimal glance it appears to be too simple that a few minutes of peering on the hex can reveal everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
0:  31 c9                 xor    ecx,ecx     ;; ecx = 0
2:  f7 e1                 mul    ecx         ;; eax = eax * ecx (set eax to 0)
4:  51                    push   ecx         ;; push 0 on stack (string end)
5:  68 2f 2f 73 68        push   0x68732f2f  ;; push "//sh" on stack
a:  68 2f 62 69 6e        push   0x6e69622f  ;; push "/bin" on stack
f:  89 e3                 mov    ebx,esp     ;; ebx = esp (esp = @"/bin//sh\0")
11: b0 0b                 mov    al,0xb      ;; eax = 0xb (sys_call_execve)
13: cd 80                 int    0x80        ;; call execve("/bin//sh")
15: 51                    push   ecx         ;; push 0 on stack
16: b0 01                 mov    al,0x1      ;; eax = 1 (sys_call_exit)
18: cd 80                 int    0x80        ;; call exit(ebx)
```

Basically, this is a shellcode that run `/bin/sh` and, then, `exit()`.